# Does import not only import but also change existing definitions?

Tags: coq

Using the following Coq code:

```
Search "prod_uncurry_subdef".
Require Import Arith.
Search "prod_uncurry_subdef".
```

prints out the following:

```
prod_uncurry_subdef: forall [A B C : Type], (A * B -> C) -> A -> B -> C
prod_uncurry_subdef: forall {A B C : Type}, (A * B -> C) -> A -> B -> C
```

Is this by intention that an (unrelated) import changes already existing definitions?

The `Arith` import changes about ten definitions, like:
`le_pred`, `pred_Sn`, `f_equal_pred`, `max_l`, ...

Even if some of them are deprecated I find this behaviour irritating. This means that adding an import might invalidate parts of a Coq file.

Is this by intention? If so why? What is the reason?

[For the files: I'm using version 8.17.1.]

Comment: I find this question very interesting but not very adapted for stackoverflow.  It points to something that looks like a design error and I thiink it should be discussed on the Coq zulip chat, where you will have better chances of attracting the attention of Coq developers.

Comment: I'm new to Coq - and therefore my idea was that I missed something and not that this might be a problem with Coq. ;-) I'll try to reach the developers using chat.

Comment: I am currently investigating, and the issue is really puzzling, even for an seasoned user like me.

Comment: `Search"prod_uncurry_subdef". Require Program.Basics. Search "prod_uncurry_subdef".` is sufficient to trigger the issue. But pasting in the contents instead doesn't trigger it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a feature of `Require Import` that loading a new development may break an existing development (that was not using the newly imported module).  This is already apparent in proof search, but in this case what is affected is the declaration of implicit arguments for existing constants.

In the case of modifying the declaration of implicit arguments for existing constants, this should be avoided, and the developers of Coq made this mistake in older version of Coq.  It seems `Arith` loads `Program` which, contains a command to change the implicit arguments of `prod_uncurry_subdef`.  It probably seemed a minor nuisance at the time, because a change from []-kind to {}-kind of implicit argument will not break many developments, and users are not suppose to use the `_subdef` objects, only the `curry` or `uncurry` objects.

But the problem is corrected in the new version of Coq (8.19), because the constant `prod_uncurry_subdef` no longer exists.

There are reflections in the design of the system to avoid this kind of nuisance in the future, in particular by making each library live in its own naming space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This clarifies things. I'll wait for 8.19 and check again.

Comment: P.S.: So maybe it would be a good idea to proof in Coq that Coq is correct. :-)

Comment: I think its already "fixed" (i.e. no prod_uncurry_subdef) in 8.18 which is out.